# Json - как передать из сервлета в ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, java-ee, сервлеты

Здравствуйте , столкнулся с проблемой : у меня есть кнопка, по клику на которую начинает действовать, этот аякс посылает на сервлет переменную(указывает какую информацию нужно получить), на сервлете исходя из полученной переменной формируется json ------- а дальше я просто хочу передать этот json объект обратно в аякс , чтобы считать полученные данные. Как это сделать ?
вот ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: $.toJSON(e.DId),//$.toJSON({'name':e.DId}),
    content: "UTF-8",
    contentType: 'application/json',            
    url: "http://localhost:8080/MyDiplomka/ServWTest", 
    success: function (data) {
            alert(data); // здесь хочу получить данные с сервлета
    }
});
```

вот сервлет:

```
Query query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Questions e where e.DId=" + wq);
List<Questions> arrQ = (List<Questions>) query1.getResultList();
for (Questions i : arrQ) {
    Query query2 = em.createQuery("select e from Answers e where e.QId=" + i.getQId());
    List<Answers> arrA = (List<Answers>) query2.getResultList();
    JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
    for (Answers j : arrA) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("AContent", j.getAContent());
        jarr.add(obj);
    }
    mainObj.put(i.getQContent(), jarr);
}
```

Получается json объект уже сформирован, но как его отправить обратно в аякс(там где хочу получить объект)? Заранее спасибо. Пс: использую json-simle библиотеку для создания json объекта

**Обновление**

Теперь

> jarr.writeJSONString(response.getWriter());

после этого, ко мне на аякс приходит [Object object] - похоже сейчас просто надо как–то извлечь полученное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам нужно примерно следующее:
`jarr.writeJSONString(response.getWriter());`

Где `response` это `HttpServletResponse`, который является входным параметром в "сервлет"